# I'm trying to move some elements around but it wont work

Tags: html, css

My code is bricked I cant move anything. I'm trying to move
all of the header links and image to the right but nothing is moving.
I tried using the position element but it doesn't work as well the only thing that  seems to work is `justify-contenter:center;` and `align-item:center;`

```css
.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: black;
  color: aliceblue;
  position: relative;
}

.head {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.image {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="logo">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Header Logo</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="head">
    <div class="1">header link one</div>
    <div class="2">header link two</div>
    <div class="3">header link three</div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>This is a website</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="web">this website has some subtext that goes here under main title. it's a smaller font and the color is lower contrast
  </div>
  <div class="image"><img src="https://english.cdn.zeenews.com/sites/default/files/styles/zm_700x400/public/2022/08/08/1075018-untitled-design-17.jpg" alt="cat">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h4>Some random information</h4>
</div>
<div></div>
<div>this is some subtext under an illustration or image</div>
<div></div>
<div>this is some subtext under an illustration or image</div>
<div></div>
<div>this is some subtext under an illustration or image</div>
<div></div>
<div>this is some subtext under an illustrationor image</div>
<div>this is an inspiring quote, or a testimonial from a customer. Maybe its just filling up space or maybe people will actually read it. who knows? all i know is that it looks nice.
</div>
<div>
  <h2>-thor, God of Thunder</h2>
</div>
<div>call to action! its time!</div>
<div>sign up for our product by clicking that button right over there!
</div>
<div>sign up</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you're looking for, you can wrap both the logo container and menu container inside another element - in this instance I've used header as that makes the most sense semantically for the type of information this section presents - then set `display: flex;` on the header - this will basically inline the two divs inside - use `justify-content: space-between;` to separate them out.

Edited to add: I've edited this to make it clearer to understand and give an example of a minimal approach to achieve the same outcome:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: aliceblue;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header .menu a {
  margin-left: .75rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="logo">
      <h1>Header Logo</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <a href='#'>Link One</a>
      <a href='#'>Link Two</a>
      <a href='#'>Link Three</a>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `flexbox`, the best way to center it is by adding `margin : auto` in the child style element.
example in your case  :

```
.cont{
display: flex;
...
}
```

add

```
.cont div,
.cont .logo,
.cont .head,
.cont img{
margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just starting from what you are requesting ("put header and image to the right"): you can right-align elements in flexboxes by using align-self.

Let us know what exactly you want to achieve so we can give better out-of-the-box answers. What's your goal?

```css
body  {
  margin: 0 0;
}

.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: black;
  color: aliceblue;
  position: relative;
}

.head {
  display: flex;
  align-self: self-end;
}

.image {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  align-self: self-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="logo">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Header Logo</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="head">
    <div class="1">header link one</div>
    <div class="2">header link two</div>
    <div class="3">header link three</div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>This is a website</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="web">this website has some subtext that goes here under main title. it's a smaller font and the color is lower contrast
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://english.cdn.zeenews.com/sites/default/files/styles/zm_700x400/public/2022/08/08/1075018-untitled-design-17.jpg" alt="cat">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h4>Some random information</h4>
</div>
<div></div>
<div>this is some subtext under an illustration or image</div>
<div></div>
<div>this is some subtext under an illustration or image</div>
<div></div>
<div>this is some subtext under an illustration or image</div>
<div></div>
<div>this is some subtext under an illustrationor image</div>
<div>this is an inspiring quote, or a testimonial from a customer. Maybe its just filling up space or maybe people will actually read it. who knows? all i know is that it looks nice.
</div>
<div>
  <h2>-thor, God of Thunder</h2>
</div>
<div>call to action! its time!</div>
<div>sign up for our product by clicking that button right over there!
</div>
<div>sign up</div>
```